# iOS .mobi sites rendering issues

Tags: ios, mobile-safari

Is there any difference between rendering sites on .mobi domain and sites on any other domains?

Comment: Why there would be? It's just a TLD.

Comment: I've got some weird differences in rendering, so the only thing left to blame is TLD

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Safari ignores viewport settings on .mobi domains. More info [here](http://www.davidroessli.com/logs/2010/04/safari_ignores_viewport_mobi_domains/).

Answer (score 0):

See also this bug report also addressing the problem of being redirected from a .mobi domain: https://bugs.webkit.org/show_bug.cgi?id=97556